# Total ordering - Partially ordered set

Tags: discrete-mathematics, divisibility, order-theory

A = {2,4,5,6,9,10,12,18,30,36,60,72}

R={(a,b) | a divides b}

I want to find a total order about partially ordered set(A,R).

If there are multiple possible values, select a large number first.

In this problem, I think total order is starting with 9.

Because 9,5,2 is a lower bound, and I have to select a large number first.

Is this right? I want to check my explanation. Also, I want to know the total order about partially ordered set(A,R).

Comment: I know whst a total order is and what a partially ordered set is. As far as I know, the phrase "total order about partially ordered set" means nothing in English. I guess it's a Google translation. Could you explain in simple words what it is? And why it should start with $9$?

Comment: Maybe 'total order compatible with a partial order(A,R)'(or just 'total order for (A,R)'?), I think. I just translate literally, so it makes a grammatical error. I'm sorry. // (Additionally) In this problem, it says 'Partially ordered set (A,R)', and 'Find the compatible total order'. // It should start with 9. I draw a hasse diagram of this problem, 2,5 and 9 is a lower bound. If there are multiple possible values, select a large number first. So, I picked 9 at first. // If I have a error of this explanation, please tell me. Thank you.

Comment: I wouldn't complain about grammar; if there was a grammatical error I'd either edit it or (more likely) ignore it. No, I really couldn't guess what the question was. "Compatible with the partial order" or "extending the partial order" would be clear; "about the partial order", not so much. Also, I wouldn't say that a total order "starts" somewhere, but I guess you are saying that $9$ is the minimum element in the total order. In other words, you want to list the elements of $A$ in increasing order (according to your total order), and among the various possible lists

Comment: corresponding to different total orders, you want the "lexicographically greatest" one. So what you want to do at each step is look at the set of minimal elements of $(A,R)$ that have not yet been listed, and pick the numerically greatest of those.  If you're doing that by hand, for a small partially ordered set, it would probably be easier if you first draw the Hasse diagram.

Comment: Doing it quickly and not very carefully I came up with $9,5,2,10,6,30,18,4,12,60,36,72$. Is that the right answer?

Comment: Thank you for your answering. I also drew a Hasse diagram, before solve this problem. Even though, I confused about how to get total orders and ask this question. // I don't have a solution, so I don't know what an answer is correct. However, when I try it, 9,5,2,10,6,4,30,18,12,60,36,72. I want to ask you, why do you put 4 between 18 and 12 ? // If I have an error of this explanation, please tell me. Thanks.

Comment: After $9,5,2,10,6$ have been listed, the minimal elements remaining are $4,18,30$. Taking the biggest ones first, the next term is $30$.

Comment: Thank you for your answering. I checked my hasse diagram again, and I also think that is right.

Comment: **Why were the definitions of A and R removed from the question?**  As it stands now, there is an answer and a lot of comments that no longer make any sense, as they seem to be pulling random numbers out of the air.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I try to edit the question, and have some mistake. I edit again. It's my first day using this platform. Pardon for my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that the total order in this case should start with 9. To select the second number, observe that all elements of A that are greater than 9 are also even, so the second number can not be any of those and thus must be one of 2,4,5 or 6. Similarly, the second number in the total order can not be 4 or 6, since those must come after 2. So you are left with 2 options: 2 or 5. Since your condition forces you to pick the larger one, you must choose 5. The third number in the total order must be 2, since everything else in A is divisible by 2. To choose the fourth number, again start eliminating the bigger numbers first. To do that, note that everything that is greater than 10 in A is a multiple of 6, so it must come after 6, and therefore can not be the fourth number in the total order. This leaves only 4, 6 and 10 as the options for the fourth number. Since, there is no way to eliminate any of these, because none of them divide each other, you must pick the greatest one. After that you can keep going with the same technique and you should end up with a total order of A that satisfies your condition.

Comment: Thank you for your answering. I read your answer and try to prove the total order for (A,R). I think the total order is 9,5,2,6,4,18,12,10,36,30,72,60. Is this right? Please answer about this comment. If I have a error of this explanation, please tell me. Thanks.

Comment: If I understood the problem correctly, the fourth number should be 10, since we narrowed down the candidates to 4, 6 and 10 and we must choose the greatest number. So the total order should start 9, 5, 2, 10, 6, 4... To determine the next number in the sequence it is helpful to look at the greater numbers first and eliminate them if possible. They can be eliminated if they have divisors in A they were not listed yet.

Comment: Thank you for your answering. I drew a hasse diagram and I used it to get a total order. In the hasse diagram, I think 10 is on the upper side of 4 and 6(just mistake), so I made a mistake. I'm sorry. // Also, I try it again. 9,5,2,10,6,4,30,60,18,12,36,72 // Additionally, I wonder 9,5,2,10,6,4,30,'60',18,12,36,72 is right or 9,5,2,10,6,4,30,18,12,'60',36,72 is right? I'm confusing about '60'. Please answer about this question. If I have a error, please tell me. Thanks.

Comment: I believe the second sequence is correct. The first one definitely is wrong, since 12 divides 60 and therefore 12 must occur earlier than 60.

Comment: After $9,5,2,10,6$ shouldn't $30$ come next instead of $4$?

Comment: Yes you are right I completely missed that. It should be 9,5,2,10,6,30,18,4...

Comment: Thank you for answering. I check my hasse diagram again and understand it.